# Separate cookies when loading separate WKWebViews?

Tags: swift, cookies, wkwebview

In my app, I have multiple WKWebViews that can visit the same social network pages. But I want to allow users have multiple accounts on those pages. Right now when two webviews go to the same network, it logs into the same account.

Is there a way to load different accounts when accessing different wkwebviews?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do this if you **force him to log out** every time he opens a new page of the same social network.